# Trigonometrical ratios of compound angles

Tags: trigonometry

If $\tan A + \tan B = b$ and $\cot A + \cot B = a$ and $A+B = Y$. 
Eliminate A and B.

I can't understand how to proceed? Please someone help!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Write both $\cot$  as $\dfrac1{\tan}$

$$\dfrac ba=?$$

$$\tan Y=\tan(A+B)=?$$

Answer (score 0):

We have: $$\cot(A+B) = \frac{1}{\tan(A+B)} = \frac{1-\tan A \tan B}{\tan A \tan B} = \frac{(\cot A + \cot B)(1-\tan A \tan B)}{(\cot A + \cot B)(\tan A\tan B)}$$ $$=\frac{1}{\tan A + \tan B}-\frac{1}{\cot A + \cot B}$$ $$\boxed{\cot Y = \frac{1}{b}-\frac{1}{a}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Formulas to be used:

$$\cot (A+B)= \dfrac{\cot A \cot B - 1}{\cot A + \cot B}$$ and $$\tan(A+B)= \dfrac{\tan A + \tan B }{1- \tan A\tan B} $$

Thus,  $$\tan Y = \dfrac{b}{1 - \tan A\tan B} \implies \tan A\tan B= 1- \dfrac b {\tan Y}= \dfrac{\tan Y - b }{\tan Y}$$

$$\cot Y = \dfrac{\dfrac{\tan Y}{\tan Y- b}- 1}{a}\implies \cot Y = \dfrac 1 b - \dfrac 1 a $$